# Vector with no zero entries in the column space over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

I am interested in the problem that was introduced here

[Spanning a vector with no zero coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156006/spanning-a-vector-with-no-zero-coordinates)

which is the following:

> Given a matrix $A \in (\mathbb{F}_p)^{m \times n}$, is there an efficient method to find a vector in its column space which does not have any 0 entries (or prove that one doesn't exist)?

The answer given in the above post shows that for every characteristic $p > 0$, there is a counterexample matrix to such a vector existing, but I would like to know of a procedure to find one such vector, or show that one cannot exist.

If it helps, I am specifically interested in $p = 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer is correct regarding the NP-completeness of Syndrome decoding, which is about finding a vector with a nonzero lower bound on the Hamming weight in the nullspace of an appropriate matrix. Actually, the original proof for $p=2$ was given in

> E. R. Berlekamp, R. J. McEliece, and H. C. van Tilborg, “On the
> inherent intractability of certain coding problems,” *IEEE Transactions
> on Information Theory*, vol. 24, no. 3, May 1978

This was generalized to arbitrary fields by Alexander Barg (there may be an English translation of this paper)

> S. Barg. Some new NP-complete coding problems. *Problemy Peredachi Informatsii^, 30(3):23–28, 1994.

The generalized case addresses your question.

Answer (score 1):

The paper S. C. Ntafos, S. L. Hakimi, *On the Complexity of Some Coding Problems*, IEEE Trans. Inform. Theory IT-**27**:6 (Nov. 1981), states that the problem of checking whether there is a binary vector $x$ with at least $w>0$ nonzero coordinates such that $xB = 0$ for a given matrix $B$ is, in general, NP-complete.

By standard linear algebra this is easily reduced to your problem for $p = 2$.

Comment: While this is correct, the original proof is from a justifiably famous paper:  E. R. Berlekamp, R. J. McEliece, and H. C. van Tilborg, “On the
inherent intractability of certain coding problems,” IEEE Transactions
on Information Theory, vol. 24, no. 3, May 1978

Comment: ...and it is the first reference in the 1981 paper :-)